# Visualization of spark machine learning in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have developed an application performing Logistic regression using Spark mllib.How can we visually perceive the results?. I mean, in R-programming,we can see the result graphically.Is there any way to visualize the results in scala spark program as well.

Comment: Check Spark Notebook, Zeppelin and Jupyter.

Comment: @maasg :Can we connect Hbase and kafka stream to the Spark notebook?

Comment: I've done Kafka without issues. I've not tried HBase but should not be a problem.

Comment: I am using databricks.Satified withits graphical aid for displaying dataframes.But not getting how we can have a visuals like ggplot in Scala.I would like to splash the Logistic regression model predicted results on a graph.

Comment: In the meanwhile, netflix open-sourced "yet another" notebook server with some nice unique features (e.g., good auto-completion, enforced reproducability): https://polynote.org/